# Ошибка при вызове метода .mean() из библиотеки pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'Company': ['COMP1', 'COMP1', 'COMP2', 'COMP2', 'COMP3', 'COMP3'],
        'Months': ['MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG'],
        'Salary': [2000, 1500, 3000, 5000, 2500, 3500]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)
df.groupby('Company').mean()
```

Работал на версии 3.12,думал ошибка в версии перешел на 3.10,всё равно осталась проблема.
Пожалуйста помогите,прогерры!!!

```
File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 12370, in _stat_function
    return self._reduce(   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 6437, in _reduce
    return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 147, in f
    result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 404, in new_func
    result = func(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, mask=mask, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 720, in nanmean
    the_sum = _ensure_numeric(the_sum)   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1701, in _ensure_numeric
    raise TypeError(f"Could not convert string '{x}' to numeric") TypeError: Could not convert string 'MARAPR' to numeric

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\pyprojects\pythonProject1\pandas&numpy.py", line 245, in <module>
    df.groupby('Company').mean()   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2452, in mean
    result = self._cython_agg_general(   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1998, in _cython_agg_general
    new_mgr = data.grouped_reduce(array_func)   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1470, in grouped_reduce
    applied = sb.apply(func)   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 393, in apply
    result = func(self.values, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1995, in array_func
    result = self._agg_py_fallback(how, values, ndim=data.ndim, alt=alt)   File "C:\Users\respu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1946, in _agg_py_fallback
    raise type(err)(msg) from err TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]
```

Comment: `df = df.groupby('Company').agg({'Salary':'mean'})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка состоит в том, что после группировки остается столбец `Months`, который содержит *не числа, а строки* — как из них вычислить среднюю величину?

Решение — существуют 2 возможности:

1. Ограничиться на столбец `Salary` - так:

   ```
   df.groupby('Company')['Salary'].mean()
   ```

   или сокращeнно как:

   ```
   df.groupby('Company').Salary.mean()
   ```

   Эти команды выводят **серию**:

   > ```
   > Company
   > COMP1    1750.0
   > COMP2    4000.0
   > COMP3    3000.0
   > Name: Salary, dtype: float64
   > ```

   Когда вы хотите вывести **датаврейм**, примените *пары квадратных скобок:*

   ```
   df.groupby('Company')[['Salary']].mean()
   ```

   > ```
   >          Salary
   > Company        
   > COMP1    1750.0
   > COMP2    4000.0
   > COMP3    3000.0
   > ```

---

2. Ограничиться на **все численные столбцы** (что в вашем случае —  с только одним таким столбцом — выдает тот же самый результат) применением параметра `numeric_only=True`:

   ```
   df.groupby('Company').mean(numeric_only=True)
   ```

   Как я сказал, вы получите тот же самый датафрейм

   > ```
   >          Salary
   > Company        
   > COMP1    1750.0
   > COMP2    4000.0
   > COMP3    3000.0
   > ```

Comment: Целую ваши мысли!